# the largest number $y$ in which $(x!)^{x+y}|(x^2)!$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Since the multiplication of $n$ consecutive integers is divided by $n!$, then $(n!)^n|(n^2)!$ with $n$ is a positive integer.

Are there any formula of the function $y=f(x)$ that shows the largest number $y$ in which $(x!)^{x+y}|(x^2)!$ with $x>1$. If so, for a positive integer $y$, **are there infinitely many** $x$ such that $(x!)^{x+y}|((x^2)!)$  (with $x, y, n$ are all positive integers) ? If not, what are the conditions of $m$ so that there are **infinitely many** $x$ such that $(x!)^{x+m}|((x^2)!)$ ? (with $m$ is a positive integer and $m \leq y$)

Comment: @ajotatxe Actually $x$ and $y$ are positive integers. I will edit in the post.

Comment: notice that if $n$ is a power of prime, then $f(n)\le 1$

Comment: I think $f(10)=2$

Answer (score 3):

Consider a prime $p \le x$.  The $p$-adic order of $x!$ is $\nu_p(x!) = \sum_{k \ge 1} \lfloor x/p^k \rfloor$.  Since $x \lfloor x/p^k \rfloor \le \lfloor x^2/p^k\rfloor$ for all $p$, we have
$(x!)^x \mid (x^2)!$.
The largest $y$ is the minimum over all such $p$ of $\lfloor \dfrac{\nu_p((x^2)!)}{\nu_p(x!)} - x \rfloor$.

Hmmm.  It appears to match [OEIS sequence A187279](https://oeis.org/A187279) (verified up to $n=10000$).

Answer (score 2):

Take the numbers from $(k-1)n+1$ to $kn$.  The first $n-1$ of them are a multiple of $(n-1)!$ so the full $n$ are a product of $k(n!)$.
So the product of all $n^2$ numbers gives $n$ lots of $n!$ and the $k$ give an $n+1$th.
That means that $y(x)\ge1$ for all $x$